# Why is this code performing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var names = ['Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Brenda', 'Lauren', 'Mary'];
  var liked = [];
  var disliked = [];

         while(names.length > 0){

          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =  names[i];
          function likeOrDislike(choice){
          if(choice == 'Like')
          {
            liked.push(names[0])
            names.splice(0, 1)
          }
          else if (choice == 'Dislike')
          {
            disliked.push(names[i])
            names.splice(0, 1)
          }

        };
   };
 });
  </script>
```

I am asking the while loop to continue until the arrays names is empty.
I am then getting the user replacing the text each time with the first name in the array. 
I am then either choosing like/dislike and then removing the first name of the array and repeating the process until the names array is empty.

However, when I load in the browser it does not load up the page as I think it is stuck in a loop

Comment: You need to check your console for errors. It'll tell you immediately that `i is not defined`. On top of that, you're defining your function inside a loop, which is a really bad idea

Answer (score 3):

Besides an undefined `i` as pointed out in the comments, you're never changing `names`

All of your processing against `names` is done within the function `function likeOrDislike()` and you never call it.

So this is happening:

- while there are names (`names >0`) then do the contents of this stub
- ... and that's it. you never change names.
- ... the function is never called.

Perhaps you're meaning to do something like this - this is just an example, totally assuming what you're trying to acheive.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var names = ['Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Brenda', 'Lauren', 'Mary'];
  var liked = [];
  var disliked = [];

  $('#yourLikeButton').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).data('name'); // on your button put data-name="Hannah"
    var idx = names.indexOf(name);
    liked.push(names[idx]); // this is if you're playing around with indexes
    names.splice(idx, 1); // this is if you're playing around with indexes
  });

  // similar for your dislike button      

 });
```